# What does "x(y) = z(w)" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax

Can somebody, please help me to understand the following syntax:

```
aaa<bbb> object_name;
func(object_name, object_name2);
ccc<ddd>(object_name) = func2(arg1, arg2);
```

I understand that in the first we declare a new object of `aaa<bbb>` class. Then we use this object together with another one to call a function, that possibly change the value of the `object_name`. I have troubles to understand the third line. In particularly the construction on the left hand side of the `=` sign. Why `object_name` is in brackets? To me it looks like we call a function. But can it be that we call a function on the left and right hand side of the `=` sign?

Comment: @Carl Norum, but what then `value1 = value2` construction does?

Comment: Lookup lvalue's and references in your C++ text book.

Answer (score 5):

A function call can return an *lvalue*, which is a type that can sensibly appear on the left hand side of an assignment expression.  The usual category of lvalue in this case is a *reference*; for example `vector<T>::front` returns a reference of type `T &`:

```
std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3};
v.front() = 99;
// v is now {99, 1, 2, 3}
```

**Advanced usage only**: it's also possible for a function to return a *prvalue* of an object type with an overloaded assignment operator such that the assignment expression has some appropriate effect; however, the standard library does not make use of this except in a few cases such as `ostream_iterator`.

Comment: I almost understood the concept. The only problem that I have is the concept or reference. I understand it as "memory address" of a variable. But, as far as I remember, if `a` is an address of a variable, we can change the value of the variable using `*`. For example `*a = 5`. So, why don't we use `*` in this case? `*(v.front()) = 99;`

Comment: @Roman The `*` operator is for use with *pointers*, which encapsulate the memory address of an object and can be indirected (using the `*` unary operator) to obtain an lvalue for that object.  References behave as an lvalue for the object they refer to throughout the lifetime of the reference, with no indirection required.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the value returned is an l-value, to which you are able to, indeed, assign a value. It could be something like this:

```
int x = 5;

template <typename T>
int& foo() { return x; }

void test()
{
  foo<long>() = 10;
}
```

Comment: I have few questions about our example. Why do you use templates? To me it looks like you "declare" type `T` before the `foo` function but later you do not use this type? So, what was the reason to declare it? Second, what does `foo` function return? Obviously it is not x, otherwise we would have `5 = 10`. Does it return address of variable `x`. If yes, why don't we use `*` to change the value located at this address: `*foo<long>() = 10;`?

Comment: The reason was intended just to provide an example similar to the one you provided. Of course in your example the template will be used somehow but since there is no implementation I can't invent how. It returns a reference, which is the address of the variable but it is meant to be used in a different way. Implementation wise, it's a pointer but it has different restrictions, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 0):

I think the left side of the third one instantiates a template function with the argument *object_name*. That it's possible to assign the value to that of *func2()* might be due to some overloading of the *operator=*?

Answer (score 0):

`ccc<ddd>` is probably a function (a specialization of a function template).  It could return a reference, in which case the referenced object will then be modified.  Or it could return a "proxy" object, which has an `operator=` which will do something useful.

Less likely, `ccc<ddd>` could be a class type (a specialization of a class template).  But for that to mean anything useful, its `operator=` would have to have some side effect other than on the temporary `ccc<ddd>` object, which would be strange.